# Filter duplicates based on one row and exclude them based on value in other row

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, duplicates

I have a df with longitudinal data. Each id has several measurements of seconds, but some of them are duplicates. I want to remove the duplicates per id in the seconds column, but I want to remove the duplicates that have NA in the measurement column, as the rows that have a value in the measurements value contain other information that I need to keep. So basically I need to identify the duplicates, and then remove the ones with NA in another column.
Edit:
But the problem is, that there are also duplicates where the measurement rows are not NA but e.g. 1 and 2. Then I need to remove the 2, as measurement 1 includes the relevant other information. Also sometimes there are duplicates that both have NA in measurement.

My df looks somewhat like this:

| id | measurement | seconds | other relevant information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5000 | blue |
| A | NA | 5000 | NA |
| A | 2 | 4000 | NA |
| B | 1 | 3400 | red |
| B | 2 | 5000 | NA |
| B | NA | 5000 | NA |
| C | NA | 3000 | NA |
| C | 1 | 3000 | blue |
| D | 1 | 2000 | green |
| D | 2 | 2000 | NA |
| D | 3 | 1000 | NA |
| D | NA | 4000 | NA |
| D | NA | 4000 | NA |

And I need it to be like this after:

| id | measurement | seconds | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5000 | blue |
| A | 2 | 4000 | NA |
| B | 1 | 3400 | red |
| B | 2 | 5000 | NA |
| C | 1 | 3000 | blue |
| D | 1 | 2000 | green |
| D | 3 | 1000 | NA |
| D | NA | 4000 | NA |

I know there is probably a pretty straight forward dplyr solution, and I tried this so far:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id, seconds) %>% filter(n() > 1)
```

and this:

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(measurement==NA & duplicates(seconds)
```

So basically the if else command I need is:

```
if "seconds" = duplicate & one measurement row == na -> delete the  na row
if "seconds" = duplicate & measurement == not na -> keep seconds = 1 row
if "seconds" = duplicate & both measurement == na -> delete randomly one
```

Comment: What happens when you have `NA` in `measurement` and it is not a duplicate? Can you include such condition in the example?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I just realized that won't work for me though, as some duplicates are in rows were the measurement value is 1 or 2 instead of NA and I still need to remove them.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems, then it excludes that row. I'll update the example above to show that

Answer (score 2):

`measurement==NA` always returns `NA`. Use `is.na(measurement)` instead. Also, you are looking for the command `duplicated`.

So:

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(is.na(measurement) & duplicated(seconds)
```

or

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(is.na(measurement), duplicated(seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out:

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(measurement) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(seconds))
```